# Prove that $A$ is bounded and find its norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider $A$ is a linear operator: $E \rightarrow E$  on Banach space $ E=C([0,1], \mathbb{R}) $. $(Af)(t) = \int_0^1{(t^2+s^2)f(s)ds}$
Prove that $A$ is bounded and find its norm.
My solution:
$||Af||=\sup \limits_{t \in [0,1]}|(Af)(t)|=\sup \limits_{t \in [0,1]} |\int_0^1{(t^2+s^2)f(s)ds}| \leq \sup \limits_{t \in [0,1]} \int_0^1{|(t^2+s^2)f(s)|ds} \leq  \sup \limits_{t \in [0,1]} (t^2+1) ||f|| = 2||f||  $
Hence $A$ is bounded.
Is my proof correct? And how to find the norm?

Comment: It is correct but you could easily find a tighter upperbound, so tight that it would be the norm.

Comment: Be careful, in order to find the norm, you should be as tight as you can be when taking inequalties. Here, you can get $\|Af\| \leq \frac 43 \|f\|$. Then, to find the norm, find a function $f$ that satisfies the equality cases of your inequalities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For boundedness, note that for any $f \in C([0,1])$,
$$|Af|=|\int_{0}^{1}(t^2+s^2)f(s)ds|\leq \int_{0}^{1}(t^2+s^2)|f(s)|ds\leq ||f||_{\infty}(t^2+\frac{1}{3})\leq \dfrac{4}{3}||f||_{\infty}$$
Thus $||A||\leq\dfrac{4}{3}$.

Now pick $f=1$, then
$$||A(1)||=sup_{t \in [0,1]}|\int_{0}^{1}(t^2+s^2)ds|=sup_{t \in [0,1]}(t^2+1/3)=\dfrac{4}{3}$$

Hence $||A||=\dfrac{4}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask one more question? If I had $E=C([0,2], \mathbb{R})$ and $(Af)(t)=\int_0^2{|(t^2+s^2)f(s)|ds}$, I would also take $f=1$, right?

Comment: I think yes. However, your norm will change, since for any $f \in C([0,2])$,
$$|Af|\leq ||f||_{\infty}(2t^2+8/3)\leq 32/3||f||_{\infty}$$